# Lexographically ordered linked list returns null pointer exception

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying to build a lexicographically ordered linked list. I planned it all out on paper and thought I need everything right, but once I insert a second or third entry it returns with a null pointer exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at DoublyLL.insert(DoublyLL.java:88)
```

If I enter, for examples:

```
"chris", "andy", then "bob", "bob" returns the excpetion.
"chris", "bob", then "andy", "andy" returns the exception
"andy", "bob", I get the same exception with the addition of at DoublyLL$Node.access$000(DoublyLL.java:148)
```

The code:

```
public boolean insert(StudentListing newListing)
{  Node n = new Node();
    if(n == null) // out of memory
       return false;
    else
    {
                    Node q = new Node();
        q = h;
        int lex;
        if (q.next == null)     // first inputed node
        {
            n.next = q.next;
            q.next = n;
            n.back = q;
            n.l = newListing.deepCopy();
            return true;
        } else                  // not first node
        {
            q = q.next;
            do
            {
               // This is the line the error is called vvv
                lex = q.l.getKey().compareTo(newListing.getKey());
               // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                if (lex < 0)
                {
                    // keep going
                    q = q.next;
                } else if (lex > 0)
                {
                    // place before q
                    n.back = q.back;
                    q.back = n;
                    n.next = q;
                    n.back.next = n;
                    return true;
                } else if (lex == 0)
                {
                    // q and listing match
                }
            } while (lex < 0);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

`Inner class`

```
 public class Node
 {   private StudentListing l;
     private Node next;
     private Node back;
     public Node()
 { }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest problem here is that, when you're inserting a new `StudentListing` to a non-empty list, you iterate over the list until you find an element that's greater than the `StudentListing` you're inserting. But if the `StudentListing` that you're inserting is greater than any element in the list, then you never find such an element, so you run off the end of the list. Before writing `q = q.next`, you need to check if `q.next == null`, and handle that case appropriately.

(There are also various little non-Java-isms in your code — for example, `if(n == null) // out of memory` will never be true, because Java indicates an out-of-memory error by raising an exception rather than by returning `null` — but none of those looks like a major problem to me.)